# Removing similar rows using GROUP BY / DISTINCT

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, distinct

I currently have a table of document paths next to an ID and other metadata, however the same file path is referenced multiple times with different IDs.

An example data set:

```
ID           FullPath
1            \\some\file\path.txt
2            \\some\file\path.txt
3            \\some\file\path.txt
4            \\another\file\path.txt
5            \\another\file\path.txt
```

I want to return a distinct set of paths and do not need the other IDs. It is probably quite a simple GROUP BY aggregate function but I can't figure it out. Please help!

I think I want something along these lines, but to be selecting the ID from the subquery instead of the path as the path causes it to return all rows. But I cant do that and GROUP BY the FullPath!

```
select *
from Documents
where FullPath in (
    select min(FullPath)
    from Documents
    group by FullPath
)
```

Results I am after:

```
ID           FullPath
1            \\some\file\path.txt
4            \\another\file\path.txt
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, there are multiple ways to do what you want.  But using the structure that you have chosen, the subquery should be returning `id` rather than the file path:

```
select d.*
from Documents d
where d.FullPath in (select min(d2.id)
                     from Documents d2
                     group by d2.FullPath
                    );
```

I more natural way to get just the two columns is:

```
select fullpath, min(id)
from Documents
group by fullpath;
```

Or, if you want other columns, use `row_number()` or `rank()`.

Comment: The second is exactly what I was after. Just over complicating things for myself! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You should use min(id)

```
  select *
  from Documents
  where id  in (
      select min(id) 
      from Documents
      group by FullPath
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use Like

EXEC('
DELETE Duplicate_Row  from (
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) RN
from Documents
) AS Duplicate_Row  WHERE Duplicate_Row.RN > 1')

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use group by:

```
SELECT id, FullPath FROM Documents GROUP BY FullPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function that takes a string and returns the string up to the last . 
Eg. fn_strip_path('\PLACE\Here\file.txt') returns '\PLACE\Here'
of course, fn_strip_path('\PLACE\Here') returns '\PLACE'

then select distinct fn_strip_path(full_path) from documents gives you want you want